# How do you print a variable in PHP that's either one element of an array, or the whole variable if it's not an array

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have $exampleVariable, which I want to print. $exampleVariable may be an array, in which case I have this set up to get the right array element, which I can then print with `print $exampleVariable[$i]`.

```
if ($_GET) {
    $i = array_search($_GET["exampleQueryString"], $exampleVariable);
} elseif (is_array($exampleVariable)) {
    $i = 0;
} else {
    $i = "";
}
```

My problem is that last `else`, if $exampleVariable is NOT an array, because then I get `print $exampleVariable[]` which doesn't work. So is there something I can put as $i to print the whole variable?

Alternatively, I considered including the brackets in $i, so I'd have for example `$i = [0];`, but in that case I don't know how I'd print it. `$exampleVariable$i` certainly won't work.

I have a good number of variables besides $exampleVariable I'll need to print, all with the same $i or lack thereof, so I'd like to not have to do anything longwinded to set each of them up individually.

This sounds way more complicated than I feel like it should, so hopefully it makes sense!

Comment: Why is there a ambiguity about the variable being either an array or a string? I recommend sanitizing and transforming your data into a consistent structure. Then, and only then, output it to the user. If find a lot of type checks to be code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do a nifty thing that is called *type casting*. That means, that you can always make a variable an array even if it is not, by prepending its name by `(array)`:

```
$exampleVariable = (array)$exampleVariable;
```

So you don't need three `if` branches at all:

```
if ($_GET) { 
    $i = array_search($_GET["exampleQueryString"], $exampleVariable);
} else {
    $i = 0;
    $exampleVariable = (array)$exampleVariable;
}
```

Comment: Typo in your closing parenthesis at the end there: `(array($exampleVariable;`

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the `(array)` cast, which will have no effect if the target is already an array:

```
$i = array_search($_GET["exampleQueryString"], (array)$exampleVariable);
```